# A CloudSearch query to find records that has terms in a list

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudsearch

I need a AWS CloudSearch structured query that will help me find records where the field value is in a list.

For example, I want to find all records where category_id field values are found in '3,62,919,552,910'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no query syntax that takes a list; you have to combine all the elements in the list using a boolean OR:

```
q=(or category_id:3 category_id:62 category_id:919)&q.parser=structured
```

Comment: How to deal with the limit of 1024 clauses?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the fields to search separately and pass in a list of values like this:

```
aws cloudsearchdomain --endpoint-url https://search-mydomain.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com search --search-query '1|2|3' --query-options='{"fields":["category_id"]}'
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I see you have added | operator to separate the values. Will each of those count as a list and contribute to the limit of 1024 clauses?